# Ubuntu 22.04 is starting and cannot start

Tags: 22.04

My workstation (Ubuntu 22.04) worked fine, a few external apps worked with SQL Server on it, created files etc. Some days ago it suggested me Update software but wrote: no free space on one of disks, I have cancelled update.
I have restarted computer and now I see the start screen "Ubuntu" and rounding progress and thats all. The system does not start.
What can I do? How to start& how to see any logs to detect the reason?

Comment: At that screen press ESC/↑/↓ to see the boot messages. Try mounting with a LiveCD or the `init=/bin/bash` trick and delete some cache/log/old/unnecessary files.

Comment: Thank you. I could manually delete files and OS started. I was a reason: no free space on the disk where OS installed